# Segmentation Fault With Strcmp With One Input

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am having an issue with the following code.

I have a global variable

```
char tokens[512][80];
```

Along with code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *input = malloc(sizeof(char) * 80);

    while (1) {
        printf("mini-shell>");
        fgets(input, 80, stdin);
        parse(input);

        if (strcmp(tokens[0], "cd") == 0) {
            cd();
        }
        else if (strcmp(tokens[0], "exit") == 0) {
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

void parse(char str[]) {
    int index = 0;
    char* str_ptr = strtok(str, " ");

    while (str_ptr != NULL) {
        strcpy(tokens[index], str_ptr);
        str_ptr = strtok(NULL, " \0\r\n");
        //printf("%d\n", index);
        index = index + 1;
    }
}
```

I found that if I enter `exit` for stdin I get a Segmentation fault, but if I enter `cd ..` for stdin I don't. Why is this so?

Comment: Use a debugger to see where the seg fault occurs. You can also use the debugger to check the value of the various variables like `token[0]` to verify whether the value is as expected or not.

Comment: How will `" \0\r\n"` be treated as a string? (hint: it will be treated as a `" "` (space) as it terminates at the first *nul-character* -- remove `'\0'`)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out using the gdb. I needed to add \n as a delimiter in the first strtok.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what the definition of the `cd()` function is, but there are a number of things that you may wish to consider in this program.

First, I don't believe there's any benefit to dynamically allocating 80 bytes of memory for the `input` buffer when you can easily do so automatically on the stack with `char input[80];` - this is free and easy and requires no deallocation when you're done.

If you do this, you derive the size with `fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)` where if you change the size of your input line from 80 to some other number, you only have to change it once: the `sizeof` on an array pulls the size directly.

Your `parse()` routine needs a little bit of help also. It's a really good idea to declare the function via the `extern` as shown so that when the compiler sees you call the function in the loop (right after the `fgets`), it knows the parameter and return types. Otherwise it has to make assumptions.

Because `parse()` is splitting apart the line you read from input, it's not required to copy the strings to some other place, so you can turn `tokens` from a multi-dimensional array into a simple array of pointers. As you run `strtok()` through the line to split up the parameters, you can store just the pointer, knowing that they will be pointing to stable data until the next `fgets()`.

Also: your code does not strictly require or use this, but adding a `NULL` pointer to the end of the `tokens` list is a really good idea: otherwise, how does the caller know how many parameters were actually entered? This code checks whether the user entered just a blank line or not.

We've also change the loop around a little bit so the `strtok()` is called just once instead of twice, including the `\n` as noted in the comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *tokens[512];

extern void parse(char *str);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char input[80];

    while (1) {
        printf("mini-shell> "); fflush(stdout); // make sure user sees prompt
        fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
        parse(input);

        if (tokens[0] == NULL) continue; // user entered blank line

        if (strcmp(tokens[0], "cd") == 0) {
            cd();
        }
        else if (strcmp(tokens[0], "exit") == 0) {
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

void parse(char *str) {
    int index = 0;

    char* str_ptr;

    while ( (str_ptr = strtok(str, " \n")) != NULL)
    {
        tokens[index++] = str_ptr;
        str = NULL; // for next strtok() loop
    }
    tokens[index] = NULL;
}
```